# How to find usages of a scala apply function in a class-instance in IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

If I call an apply method from an instance of a Scala class

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = new A(2)
    a(2)
    a(10)
  }

  class A(a: Int) {
    def apply(a: Int): A = new A(a)
  }
}
```

i am not able to find its usages with *Alt + F7* or Ctrl+click.

<strike>Is there any way to find usages of a scala apply method in IntelliJ?</strike>

---

**EDIT:** In the first rendition of this question I did not understand that this is only a problem for apply-method for instances of classes. It works for apply-method in companion objects, as @sebszyller demonstrated below.

This is probably a bug in IntelliJ. Closing the question.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *all* but Ctrl-Click on the method call `Add10(13)` should go to the definition or if clicked on the definition should show the usage.

Comment: I the method is called like Add10(13), Ctrl-Click on apply does not show the usage. "No usages found."

Comment: It does for me, though. What version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: Huh, that is interesting. We had a discussion about it in our team, and it does not work for anyone of us. I use 2016.2.1. One addition, if the method is called with Add10.apply(13) I will find the usage.

Comment: Hmm, could you show me a piece of code where it should find the usages? I will post a snippet that works for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug in IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet works for me.

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a1 = A(1)
    val a2 = A(2)
  }

  class A(a: Int)
  object A {
    def apply(a: Int): A = new A(a)
  }
}
```

*Ctrl-Click* gives me a list that shows both `A(1)` and `A(2)`. Cannot show the screenshot at the moment, unfortunately.

Works as well with your example; gives me a list of two usages as well.

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {   
    val eleven = Add10(1)
    val twelve = Add10(2)
  }

  object Add10 {
    def apply(a: Int): Int = a + 10
  }
}
```

I'm on 2016.2 now but I have been using the option for as long as I can remember.

UPDATE:

I figured this out. Consider the following snippet:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = new A(2)
    val b = new A(10)

    val a1 = a(2)
    val a2 = a(2)
    a.doSthElse

    val b1 = b(10)
    val b2 = b(10)

    val apply1 = a.apply _
    val apply2 = b.apply _ 
    val apply3 = a.apply(10)

    val tenFromA = apply1(10)
    val tenFromB = apply2(10)


  }

  class A(a: Int) {
    def apply(a: Int): A = new A(a)

    def doSthElse = println("sth else")
  }
}
```

It seems that `apply` is linked to the instance of the class and not the definition itself. In the following snippet, if you click on `a` it will show all you all the usages: `a(2)` twice, `a.doSthElse` and `a.apply _` and similarly for `b`. I included three explicit calls in the form of `a.apply _`, `b.apply _` and `a.apply(10)`. Clicking on `def apply` does indeed show the list of these three usages. That it is not able to figure out that `a(2)` is an `apply` call is a bug, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this one. My example above was written straight into StackOverflow without testing it. I apologize for that, because when I tried it (along with your A(1)/A(2) example), it works for me as well. So I went back to my original piece of code, and see that is not infact an object but a class. And IntelliJ is not finding the use of apply() for an instance of a class. Will update original question.

Comment: Glad I could help. Just mark it as closed @ØyvindHolmstad, so that it does not show up in the feed anymore.

Comment: Problem not solved though. Still can't find usages of apply() for instances of scala classes. Could it be an IntelliJ bug?

Comment: Alright then, give me a snippet of code so that I could try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Added some extra info @ØyvindHolmstad

Comment: Thanks. Then we agree that this is an IntelliJ bug :)